# ¿Hacer que el input de texto de HTML5 solo permita números y un punto?

Tags: html5

¿Me podrán explicar la manera más rápida para hacer que un input de tipo texto me permita poner números + un punto ('.')?

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057595/allow-2-decimal-places-in-input-type-number/34058008

Comment: Para realizar lo que deseas, podrías hacerlo mediante **expresiones regulares** o `Javascript/JQuery`... intenta y nos comentas como te va

Comment: Hola, llevas algo de tiempo en el sitio, ayudanos realizando tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizaría:

`pattern="\d*\.?\d*"` para números con o sin decimales. Valida: `2.45`, `123.5`
`123`, `.7`

`pattern="\d*(\.\d+)"` valida `2.45`, `123.5` y `.7` pero NO valida `123`.

explicación:

`\d`      digito

`\d*`     0 o más dígitos

`()`      grupo

`(\.\d+)` grupo de un punto `\.` más uno o más dígitos `\d+`

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="input_name" pattern="\d*(\.\d+)" required="required" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('número con decimales por favor')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" title="Numero con decimales">
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: enxaneta, he revertido la edición a tu respuesta. Te sugiero presionar el botón "[edit]" si consideras que debe haber un cambio. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto es lo que buscas, pero puedes utilizar validaciones con regex

```
<input type="text" name="input_name" pattern="[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*" title="Numero con decimales">
```

Te dejo el link a la [referencia](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

Puedes probarlo tu mismo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern)